# CSS3: link doesn't transition with absolute path as href in Chrome on Mac 

Tags: html, google-chrome, css

I'm having some trouble with the CSS transition property with absolute links in the href in Chrome on my Mac.

**I have**

```
a {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;  
     -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;  
      -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;  
       -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;  
          transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a { color: #333;
a:hover { color: #c3dd11; }
```

**and**

```
<a href="/home/">Link fades</a> 
<a href="#">Link fades</a>  
<div id="header">
        <nav>
            <a href="http://danielcgold.com">Link doesn't fades</a>  
    </nav>
</div>
```

Here's a JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bYBxC/

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: could you provide more info on the conditions it does not work? I tried on FF 8.0 (Ubuntu) and both links worked the same...

Comment: got any more info on browser? viewing you fiddle with ff 8 and both links work

Comment: Both links work for me here in Chrome.

Comment: I think I got the exact same thing. I couldn't work out what it was that all the not-working transitions had in common but you're right, it's the absolute url's. I use Chrome 16 on a Mac.

Comment: @jfriend00 Which version of Chrome do you have? I get this very issue in Chrome 16 on both Mac and PC.

Comment: Yeah, I first noticed it on chrome on my Mac. It took about an hour of playing around before I identified the source of the issue.

Comment: It works fine for me with Chrome, Firefox and Opera on Win (didn't bother testing the rest). Sounds like some weird bug with Chrome on Mac. Have you tested in Safari? Anyway, you should definitely report this. http://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidlines-for-the-mac-linux-builds

Comment: I'm seeing it working fine in Chrome 16.0.912.63 m on Windows Vista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug is fixed in the latest version of chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same thing. I couldn't work out what it was that all non-working links had in common. Reading you're question I thought "Aha!" but I've just checked and some absolute url's are showing the transitions just fine. What I have noticed though is that the absolute urls that *don't* have `www.` at the beginning don't show the transition but the ones that do, do. I notice in your example there is no `www.` in front of the domain name. Try adding that and see if it works. This appears to be a Chrome bug.

### Edit

Just been playing around with the fiddle and both links are showing the transition regardless of the url. That wasn't the case at first. Very strange bug indeed.

Comment: Indeed, I thought I just needed to restart chrome because I'm pretty sure it worked before. I made changes to the nav and tested it and it was broken. I thought it was cached so I made the fiddle but the same thing happened! Very strange.